# How can I return multiple data using ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to return a multiple data from database, then I'll pass it to jquery using ajax & json but the problem is its not working. Can anyone help me to fix it? Here is my code.

**Jquery**

```
$('.highlight').click(function() {  
        var y = $(this).find("td").eq(0).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
        var x = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
        var z = $(this).find("td").eq(2).text();
         //$('#ClassModal').modal('show');
        $("#spanclass").text(x);
        $("#spanclass2").text(z);
        $('#ClassModal').modal('show');     
        $.ajax({ 
              type:"GET",
              url: 'db_loadStud.php', 
              data: 'year='+x+'&subject='+z, 
              dataType: 'json', 
              success: function(data){
                for(var x=0;x<data.length; x++){
                    $(".studname").find("span").text(data[0]+", "+data[1]);
                }
              }
        });
        return false;       
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();
include("db_conf.php");
$fid = $_SESSION['fid'];
$year = $_GET['year'];
$sub = $_GET['subject'];
$sql = "SELECT si_lname, si_fname, si_mname,si_studentno FROM `student_info` a";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM student_enrolled WHERE se_active='True') b ON a.si_studentno=b.se_id";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN tblcourses c ON b.se_level=c.c_level WHERE c_level='$year' AND c_subject='$sub' AND c_teacher = '$fid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$arr;
    while($array = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

        echo json_encode($array);

    }


?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ClassModal" style="margin-left:-400px;margin-right:auto;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ClassModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"  style="width:1000px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#0a4595;color:#fff">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><center>Landstand of Knowledge Learning School, Inc. [ <span id="spanclass"></span> - <span id="spanclass2"></span> ]</center></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height:470px;">              
                <div style="float:left;border:1px solid #0a4595;width:200px;height:435px;"> 
                    <div style="width:100%;height:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #0a4595;background-color:#0a4595;padding:5px;font-size:12;color:#fff">
                        <center>STUDENTS</center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="studname" style="width:100%;height:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #0a4595;padding:5px;font-size:12;">
                                <span id="studname"></span>
                    </div>

                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I know this was posted 2+ years ago and the answer below likely helps part of the issue but I see another issue with the PHP code...

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop, you are always overriding the contents of the span instead of adding contents to the existing one so only the last item in the array will be visible

```
$(".studname").empty();
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    $(".studname").find("span").append(data[x][0] + ", " + data[x][1]+'<br />');
}
```

Comment: @Lestr1992 can you try `.append(data[x]+'<br />');`

Comment: i think my problem is at 

     success: function(data){
                for(var x=0;x<data.length; x++){
                    $(".studname").find("span").text(data[0]+", "+data[1]);
     }

when i check on my browser it returns my request but when it goes to success it doest returns.

Comment: thank you my friend, i resolve it by using jsonp :) but by the what it helps me :D